# js if statment to refresh iframe by checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, iframe, checkbox

i have some code that is executed by a checkbox which then executes after a given time the it runs some code with a function name "ee()", I've texted it with alert and it doesnt execute whatsoever and instead stays dull the code is below please explain;

```
if (rap.checked == true){
      setTimeout(function () {
   ee();
  }, 100);
  } else {
    

      }
```

Comment: That is only going to run if the checkbox is checked when the page loads. It will not keep checking for it to be checked. You are going to have to add an event listener to the checkbox for the change.

Answer (score 0):

I need so see more code before answering, One possible thing is that it's being run right as the script is loaded. To fix that, you have to put it into a function like this. And then have the function be pointed to by a button.

```
function name(params) {
  if (rap.checked === true) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      ee();
    }, 100);
  } else {

  }
}
```

Comment: That's more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: I can't comment on the project, I need more rep -_-